# Animating the height change of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which is a `subview` of a `UIScrollView` (this is required because of stuff above and below the collection view.

Anyway...

The collection view shows three items per row and only two rows to begin with.

The first five items are actual items and the last item is a "See More" item.

When the last item is pressed I change the number of items shown and update the collection view...

```
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 5 ; i<self.facilities.count ; i++) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
}

// changing the tableCollapsed bool updates the number of items
if (self.isTableCollapsed) {
    self.tableCollapsed = NO;
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} else {
    self.tableCollapsed = YES;
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
}
```

I then run...

```
[self setHeightAnimated:YES];
```

Which does this...

```
- (void)setHeightAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = (NSInteger) ceilf((CGFloat)[self getNumberOfItems] / self.numberOfItemsPerRow);

    self.heightConstraint.constant = numberOfRows * self.rowHeight;

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             [self layoutIfNeeded];
                         }];
    } else {
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

This always works and sets the right height and it gets the correct value of `animated` when it should be `YES` or `NO`. However, it never animates. It just switches to the new height immediately.

I'm guessing this is because of some layout code that is run or something but I was wondering if anyone knows how best to do this so that the height changes properly with the animation I have specified.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK! After a couple of hours I found a solution.

I have moved the insertion block into a method like this...

```
- (void)addItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths {
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    }];
    [self setHeightAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This uses a method that I didn't know about the `performWithoutAnimation` to add items to the collection view. Then I animate the height independently of that.

Works like a charm.

The reverse works also...

```
- (void)removeItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths {
    [self setHeightAnimated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
        }];
    }];
}
```

This animates the height first and then removes the items without animation.